# Update model parameter with new data, discarding old data

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, statistics, polynomials, online-algorithms

I have [**this**](https://pastebin.com/A3s9dUKp) dataset, and I am using `y = (a * x^n) / (b + x^n)` Hill function as the model, where `a` is the limit of the Hill curve, `b` is the point at which `a/2` is reached (for `n` = 1) and `n` is the cooperativity or steepness of the curve.

Currently, I am storing all `x,y` values and computing the parameters `a,b,n` using black-box optimization to minimize the least-squares error. (I currently use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, a standard optimizer that can minimize an arbitrary objective function.  In my case, the objective function is the total least-squares error.).

When new data points come along, I re-calculate the parameters with the old+new data, i.e. I append the new data to the old tuple of `x,y` values and get the new parameters.

**Is there a way to update the parameters of the model without storing all of the previous old data points, once the initial parameters are obtained from the previous data points?** I am looking for some kind of on-line algorithm to tackle the problem, but have no clue how to go about it. I read a [**blog-post**](http://erikerlandson.github.io/blog/2012/07/05/deriving-an-incremental-form-of-the-polynomial-regression-equations/) that shows how do this for polynomial regression, but as the power of `x` which is `n` is a parameter to the model, I have no idea how to extend the approach to my specific function.

I am looking for a solution like so: I fit the curve to the first 1000 data points and have my parameters. Next, I discard some or all of the old data. Then, when I see the 1001st point I simply update my parameters and plot the curve again and so on for every new data point.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, does the question in it's current form work for CS Stack Exchange?

Comment: Yes, it's on topic.

Comment: Check my edit to see if it accurately represents your problem.  (And welcome to CS.SE!  I think the question is on-topic and suitable here, after the edits to focus on an algorithm rather than an implementation.  I hope someone will be able to help you.)

Comment: Must $n$ be an integer ? If so, a dumb engineer's method (parse that either way) is to take the best of $opt(n-1), opt(n), opt(n+1)$ on new + "some" old data. (I believe [scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) can be run incrementally, starting from previous $x \ grad \  jac$.)